# Cross including the same table relations in EF Code Throws an error Multiplicity constraint violated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have cross relations with the same table, in 3rd object.
When I try to insert new object, got an error :

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role
>   'OrgOwners_Organisation_Target' of the relationship
>   'GBankDataSource.OrgOwners_Organisation' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

I've tried to annotate `[ForeignKey("...")]` in any of the classes, but nothing happend. EF allways choose one field (OrgRefID in this sample) and use it or both relations, while OrgID are not used.

```
public class OrganisationInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int OrgID { get; set; }
...
    public virtual List<OrgOwners> OrgOwners { get; set; } // object that throws error 

}


public class OrgOwners
{
    [Key]
    public int OrgOwnerID { get; set; }

    public int OrgID { get; set; } //Suppose to be a ForeignKey for (OrganisationInfo OrgOwners List)
    public int? OrgRefID { get; set; }
...
    [ForeignKey("OrgRefID")]
    public virtual OrganisationInfo Organisation { get; set; } //(Suppose to use OrgRefID as ForeignKey)

}
```

When I add a record to OrgOwners without Organisation  `( Organisation =null)` - it is OK. But when I do

var first = new OrganisationInfo(); //First organisation DB.OrganisationInfoes.Add(first);

var nextOrg = new OrganisationInfo(); //second organisation

first.OrgOwners = new list();

var Owner = new OrgOwners(); Owner.Organsiation = nextOrg;

first.OrgOwners.Add(Owner); // Add Owner with the second organisation to the First one.

I got an error.

> Multiplicity constraint violated.

OrgOwner.Organisation - is NOT the same OrganisationInfo as in root of OrgOwners list. It must be different OrganisationInfo items, related to OrgRefID ForeignKey.

Answer (score 1):

It's because EF by default automatically "pairs" the navigation properties where possible to form a relationship. In your case, it pairs `OrganizationInfo.OrgOwners` collection navigation property with `OrgOwners.Organization` reference navigation property, hence takes and uses the associated with it `OrgRefID` FK.

One way to resolve the issue is to add a second reference navigation property to `OrgOwners` and associate it with the `OrgID` property via `ForeignKey` attribute *and* `OrganizationInfo.OrgOwners` collection navigation property via `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public int OrgID { get; set; } //Suppose to be a ForeignKey for (OrganisationInfo OrgOwners List)

[ForeignKey("OrgID")]
[InverseProperty("OrgOwners")]
public virtual OrganisationInfo OwnerOrganization { get; set; }
```

To do that without changing the entity model, you should configure the relationship via fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrganisationInfo>()
    .HasMany(e => e.OrgOwners)
    .WithRequired() // no inverse navigation property
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrgID); // <--
```

Comment: Nothing helped, still have The role 'OrgOwners_Organisation_Target' of the relationship 'GBankDataSource.OrgOwners_Organisation' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

OrgOwner.Organisation - is NOT the same OrganisationInfo as in root of OrgOwners list. It must be different OrganisationInfo items, related to OrgRefID ForeignKey.

Comment: Well, I used the fluent API approach, created and applied migration which created the two tables with the correct relationships. Then used your sample code, added `context.Organizations.Add(first); context.SaveChanges();` at the end and it works. So the above is solving the modelling issue, now make sure (1) the database reflects the model and (2) you do the operations correctly.

Comment: The fluent API approach is really worked! , but the annotation method is not. Thank you so much, I have find the way!

Answer (score 0):

Full worked example:

```
public class OrganisationInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int OrgID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrgOwners> OrgOwners { get; set; } 

}

public class OrgOwners
{
    [Key]
    public int OrgOwnerID { get; set; }
    public int OrgID { get; set; }
    public int? OrgRefID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrgRefID")]
    public virtual OrganisationInfo Organisation { get; set; } 

}



modelBuilder.Entity<OrganisationInfo>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.OrgOwners)
                    .WithRequired() 
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrgID);
```